# How to read data from a file and pass it to the FPGrowth algorithm in Spark/PySpark

Tags: python, algorithm, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to read data from a file (items separated by comma) and pass this data to the FPGrowth algorithm using PySpark.

My code so far is the following:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local", "Assoc Rules", pyFiles=[])

txt = sc.textFile("step3.basket")
data =  txt.map(lambda line: line.split(",")).collect()
rdd = sc.parallelize(data, 2)

from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth

fpg = FPGrowth(minSupport=0.02, minConfidence=0.6)
model = fpg.fit(rdd)
```

But when I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d34039dccad5> in <module>()
      2 
      3 fpg = FPGrowth(minSupport=0.02, minConfidence=0.6)
----> 4 model = fpg.fit(rdd)

~/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self._fit(dataset)
     65         else:
     66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

~/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 265         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    266         return self._create_model(java_model)
    267 

~/local/spark/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    260         """
    261         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 262         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):
```

AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute '_jdf'

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPGrowth from pyspark.ml.fpm takes a pyspark dataframe, not a rdd. convert rdd into dataframe and then pass. Check http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth.fit

Or import fpgrowth from mllib

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
```

EDIT:
There are two ways you can proceed.

1.Using rdd method

Taking straight from the docs,

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
txt = sc.textFile("step3.basket").map(lambda line: line.split(","))    
                            #your txt is already a rdd
                            #No need to collect it and parallelize again

model = FPGrowth.train(txt, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10) #change parameters according to need
                                                              #model is ready
```

2.Using dataframe (which i would suggest is a better method)

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
df = sc.textFile("step3.basket").map(lambda line: (line.split(","),))
        .toDF('items')

fp = FPGrowth(minSupport=0.2, minConfidence=0.7)
model = fp.fit(df)  #model is ready!
```

Comment: I am new to PySpark, can you explain how do I read the data from the file into a dataframe?